# Creating dynamic subdomain using PHP Custom CMS?

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system, subdomain

I am somehow confused to analyse a project. Client says "I need an admin panel using PHP that create subdomain on wizard", i.e like he wants www.domain.com/sub1, www.domain.com/sub2, www.domain.com/sub3 etc. each sub domain may contain different header, menu, content, footer etc. I am really confused in "How do I make PHP admin panel that creates a directory and files for each subdomain?". I hope you got it, otherwise I am ready to discuss it more.

Thanks.

Comment: Those are not subdomains. That's easy to redirect with .htaccess to a php script using RewriteEngine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why making a directory for each "domain"? You can use .htaccess and a database.

Comment: To keep it clean, you should always have different directories for each subdomain.

Comment: Ok, If I handle it with .htacess and DB, but then how would I create different header, footer, contents for each sub domain?

Comment: You can store the data inside the database with the name of the "domain" and then selecting the domain data and show inside the template

Comment: Ok, Thanks got some ideas though.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you have something on this:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php